# Galois-theory - a question about the galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I am dealing with galois theory at the moment and I came across with an example in the lecture and I got a question:

Let $K=\mathbb Q$ and $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\subset \mathbb C$. Lets consider the field-extension $L/K$

Because of $[L:K]=[L:K(\sqrt{2})]\cdot [K(\sqrt{2}):K]=4$

**Question 1:** How we can argue that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}$ in $K(\sqrt{2})$ is still $x^2-3?$ I.e. we have to show that $\sqrt{3}\notin K(\sqrt{2})$. It seems trivial, but i would like to see an argument.

Because of $L$ is a splitting field of $f(X)=(x^2-3)(x^2-2)$ $L/K$ we have a galois-extension.

**Question 2:** Then we concluded that $|G|=|Gal(L/K)|=4$ but why? Does it holds that $|[L:K]|=|G|$ in any case? The definition of $Gal(L/K)$ is $Gal(L/K)=Aut_K(L)$, but i thought that $K$-automorphisms are already defined if we know the images of all generater of the extension, hence $|G|$ must be 2.

The rest is clear to me. We noticed that there are only $2$ groups with order $4$, namely $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$. And we saw that this group cant be cyclic, hence must be $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$.

I hope someone can answer my questions. Also if someone knows a useful link to this topic I will be very glad about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you cannot argue that $[L/K(\sqrt 2)] = 2$ without knowing the degree of minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 3$ over $K(\sqrt 2)$. What you do know is that the degree is at most $2$, since it is the root of $x^2-3$. Thus, you can conclude $[L/K]\leq 4$ and that it is divisible by $2$, because $[K(\sqrt 2)/K] = 2$. So, $[L/K]$ is either $2$ or $4$. If it were $2$, it would imply $[L/K(\sqrt 2)] = 1$, thus $\sqrt 3\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$, and you can proceed as Andrea suggested, deriving contradiction and concluding $[L/K] = 4$.

For the second question, it is one of the first thing one proves in Galois theory that the number of automorphisms coincides with the degree of the extension. It can easily be proved by induction and the fact that $[L/K][K/E] = [L/E]$. But, you are mistaken when you say that there are only $2$ possibilities where automorphism can send generators. $\sqrt 2$ can be sent to $\pm\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ to $\pm\sqrt 3$, thus $4$ possibilities, as wanted. This actually directly gives $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K) = \mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$, as you stated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw that we will prove that $Aut_K(L)=|Gal(L/K)|$ holds. But there are still some things I don't understand. I really was thinking that all K-automorphisms are determined by the images of the generators. Why are we not consider automorphisms which maps $\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{2}+1$ for example?

Comment: Well, they are determined by the images of generators, that is the property of vector spaces, which are free modules. But, why $\sqrt 2$ can't be sent to $\sqrt 2 + 1$ is different question. Well, let's say you have $K$-linear field automorphism $\phi$, polynomial $f\in K[x]$ and it's root $\alpha$. Then $0 = \phi(f(\alpha)) = f(\phi(\alpha))$ because $\phi$ is $K$-linear and ring homomorphism. Thus, $\phi(\alpha)$ is the root of $f$. And if you assume that $f$ is minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, you get that $\alpha$ can be sent only to it's conjugates, thus $\pm\sqrt 2$ in case of $x^2 - 2$.

Answer (score 4):

(1) Suppose that $\sqrt{3}=a+b\sqrt{2}$ with $a,b\in\Bbb Q$. Taking squares
$$
(a^2+2b^2)+2ab\sqrt{2}=3.
$$
Can you derive a contradiction?

(2) The cardinality of the Galois group of a Galois extension always coincides with the degree. What are the generators in this case, and what is the effect of the automorphisms on them?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! (1): We got a contradiction because a comparison of coefficients yields that $ab=0$, hence $a=0$ or $b=0$ but then we have that $a^2=3$ or $2b^2=3$, hence $a$ or $b$ is irrational. (2): We got 2 generators of the galois extension, but I don't understand why we only look at permutations between $\pm\sqrt{2}$ and $\pm\sqrt{3}$ (see my comment in the other answer)

Comment: @Epsilondelta: A Galois automorphism needs to send a root of a polynomial to another root of the same polynomial. Since $\sqrt{2}$ is a root of $x^2-2$, any Galois automorphism either fixes $\sqrt{2}$ or sends it to $-\sqrt{2}$. Since your field is generated by $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ you have 4 different ways an automorphism can act on them, hence on the field itself.